# Why do @synthesize variable names begin with an _?

Tags: objective-c

I'm just starting to use Objective-C and I need to clarify something

When I @synthesize a @property, it is common convention to do the following:

```
@interface Class : ParentClass

@property propertyName

@end

@implementation

@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;

@end
```

I've seen plenty of questions and answers suggesting that "_propertyName" is widely accepted as the "correct" way to synthesize properties.  However, does it serve ANY purpose? Or is it merely to increase readability and identify instance variables?

Comment: Why dont you just try and search before asking.Lots of info already in forum

Comment: I did search.  I found multiple similar questions, but they didn't seem to be asking the same thing… And if they were, I misunderstood them.

Comment: I have put some links in the answer see that

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5170703/1704346, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5170739/1704346, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=synthesize%20in%20objective%20c&oq=synthesize%20&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3j62l2.7620j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802851/objective-c-synthesize-property-name-overriding  (cc @LithuT.V)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How does an underscore in front of a variable in an ObjC class work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/822487)

Comment: And here's another 16: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582448/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049269/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371489/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174277/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5659156
http://stackoverflow.com/q/837559/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146244/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10651535/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6124109/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145373/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521254/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064283/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696359/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5521499/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466496/
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114587/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

> You Can Customize Synthesized Instance Variable Names
>
> As mentioned earlier, the default behavior for a writeable property is
>   to use an instance variable called _propertyName.
>
> If you wish to use a different name for the instance variable, you
>   need to direct the compiler to synthesize the variable using the
>   following syntax in your implementation:
>
> @implementation YourClass @synthesize propertyName =
>   instanceVariableName; ... @end

Also:

> Note: The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable
>   in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor
>   method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite
>   property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will
>   assume that you are taking control over the property implementation
>   and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically. If you still
>   need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be
>   synthesized: @synthesize property = _property;

Comment: OK, we can all read documentation, now answer his question.

Answer (score 2):

It makes it so that if you accidentally leave off "self." you get a nice compiler error instead of silently not having your methods called.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this the generated accessor actually got to know which variable(iVar) to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, It increases the readability & also separates the private & public variables to understand & use.  Private variable of Class generally written in "*propertyName" format.You can say it is a coding convention where Private Variable Names use '*' as prefix and Public Variables or Property Names are lowerCamelCase.